# Exercise of a sequence given epsilon

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

I plan to solve the following exercise

given $\epsilon>0$, calculate $m_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge m_\epsilon$ it is verified that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$, in this case you have to

$x_n= n^{2}a^{n}$ and $x=0$, also $|a|<1$

Well, consider that $$0 \le x_n=|x_n-0|=|n^{2}a^{n}|< \epsilon$$

From where

$$|a^{n}|<\frac{\epsilon}{n^{2}}$$

I have been able to find that, however I have not been able to find the value of $m_\epsilon$.Any help please?

Comment: When you say that you want to **calculate** $m_\epsilon$, do you mean to find the smallest? If it works for $m_\epsilon$, then it works for all integers $\geq m_\epsilon$.

Comment: Your question seems quite unclear to me, but it looks like you are trying to prove that $n^2a^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ when $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|a|<1$.